Batch; how to read the result of a command and run another command if it fails
My work uses this command called zac, it's for zenworks. Basically, you run zac ps, and it outputs this:
Processing command:  ps

Starting patch scan .....

and then it will either output:
The patch scan has completed and reported results to the server

or:
There was an error scanning the computer:  ANALYZE_FAILED

or:
There was an error scanning the computer:  FAILED_TO_REPORT_RESULTS

What I want to do is to make a batch script that figures out which of these three outputs it spat out, and run a command accordingly.
For example, if it outputs ANALYZE_FAILED I want it to run zac bv "discover applicable updates", or if it outputs FAILED_TO_REPORT_RESULTS I need it to delete a file so the scan works.
Is there a way to do this with batch?

You might check whether the command sets the ERRORLEVEL when it exits.  That's a lot easier to handle.

You can check that by adding ECHO %ERRORLEVEL% & Pause as the next command, and reading its output for each of your three scenarios. If the error codes returned are not definitive for you, it may be necessary to find a utility or alternative scripting language to tee the reported results, such that you can pipe a copy through find.exe or findstr.exe for further processing as needed. Alternatively, you'd need to immediately grab the latest results from the server upon completion of the command for your analysis.

This Batch file does exactly what you described...
@echo off
setlocal

zac ps > output.txt
type output.txt

for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in (output.txt) do set "output=%%a"
if %output% == ANALYZE_FAILED zac bv "discover applicable updates"
if %output% == FAILED_TO_REPORT_RESULTS del theFile.ext


My questions Aacini, as I have no knowledge of how zac.exe works, is, "does that prevent any stdOut report being sent to the server"? and, are you telling us that all output is sent via stdOut, rather than that and/or stdErr?

I don't know how zac utility works either, so I based my solution on the OP's description. If the requirements are incomplete, I think it is up to the OP to verify this point and provide more details if necessary...

this is basically exactly what i need, thanks! how do I put it in a loop so after it deletes the file or runs zac bv it runs zac ps? sometimes one error happens, sometimes both happen, and sometimes none happen

Your description is not clear enough. I suggest you to post a new question with my code and clearly describe the missing parts: A loop over several files? What are the file names (with extension)? What exactly you want to do in each of the three cases? Etc... If you want a faster response, please advice me here of the new question.

And I encourage you to mark this answer as Best Answer...
